# TaskCompletionSource performs slowly

Tags: c#, .net, taskcompletionsource

By looping through multiple instances of TaskCompletionSource in the synchronous method, more than 5 programs will become slow to execute, but in the asynchronous method you don't have this problem.

This is problematic code Using the synchronization method, the execution becomes slow, creating one in about 1 second

```
Parallel.For(1, 100, (index) =>
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("start:");
    var t = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    count++;

    System.Console.WriteLine("end:" + count + "\n");
    t.Task.Wait();
    System.Console.WriteLine("ended:");
});
```

This is No problem code，Execute very fast

```
Parallel.For(1, 100, async (index) =>
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("start:");
    var t = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    count++;

    System.Console.WriteLine("end:" + count + "\n");
    await t.Task;
    System.Console.WriteLine("ended:");
});
```

Comment: It can be interesting for you [Task.Delay(..).Wait()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648014/what-is-going-on-with-task-delay-wait)

Comment: TaskCompletionSource isn't slow. It's not running *at all*. It provides a Task whose state can be switched when some other code calls `.SetResult`. No code signals the TCS in your code so it never completes

Comment: The *second* snippet is the actual bug. It doesn't await anything in parallel, it fires of 100 tasks and never awaits for them. Those 100 tasks are still blocked and will never print `ended:`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe the problem clearly. The above is the pseudo code I wrote. I just want to restore the concurrent scene. I don't need to wait for the output "ended", call and create the TaskCompletionSource instance through the synchronous method. In the case of concurrency, create the instance more than My CPU core number will be slow, I have tried setting ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100); but this does not solve the problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have some misunderstanding on `Parallel.For()`.

First of all, `Parallel.For()` is not designed for asynchronous tasks. It is already mentioned in many post:

- [How to correctly write Parallel.For with async methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284202/how-to-correctly-write-parallel-for-with-async-methods)
- [Nesting await in Parallel.ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach)

Imagine in a kitchen, you have 5 cooks(thread), `Parallel.For()` is assigning each pending dish one by one to each cook, straight forward. But `async-await`, is assigning 'agreement promising I will make a dish' to cook, that's an appointment only thread kick start it and 'finish' the process.

That's why you get very fast response in `async-await` example. But this line:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("ended:");
```

is not printed. When the working Thread meet the `await`, this task ends.

---

Let's simplify the example you are using, `TaskCompletionSource` is not a good example for testing different between `async-await` and `Parallel.For()`.

```
//Async
Parallel.For(1, 100, async (index) =>
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("start:" + index);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    System.Console.WriteLine("ended:" + index);
});
//Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
```

`Async-await` one will never print `ended: index` in this case. Try adding a line `Task.Delay(2000).Wait();` at the end, you can notice `ended:index` is finally printed.

Try reducing `1000` to `1` in delay, it may print some `ended` but it is **NOT guarantee** by the `Parallel.for`, which means you tasks are not waited at all inside the `Parallel.for()` threads, it is hold by another threads for `async-await`.

```
//Sync

Parallel.For(1, 100, (index) =>
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("start:" + index);
    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
    System.Console.WriteLine("ended:" + index);
});
```

How about parallel, yes, it is 'slow', starting thread and task-scheduler take cost. But it is really telling you tasks are finished before the end of program.

Comment: If _tasks are not waited at all_, then "ended.." should be printed immediately Or do you mean `Parallel.For` tasks?

Comment: @Rekshino, I adjust the wording, sorry for making confuse.

Comment: @Rekshino MatrixTai's explanation is correct. `ended:` runs only if the TCS is signalled, which never is. The OP's second snippet will start 100 task, 4 or 8 at a time (depending on the number of cores) and never wait for them. It will finish almost immediatelly. The tasks themselves though will stop when they reach `await t.Task;` and never print `ended:`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos His answer is partly correct. _Async-await one will never print ended: index, which means you tasks are not waited at all inside the Parallel.for() scope_ refers to his snippet and it's wrong. it will print "ended" if we will wait __outside__ the `Parallel.For` loop. So in async code of MatrixTai in inside `Parallel.For` we will wait and print "ended", outside we don't wait.

Comment: @Rekshino, `await` is not `wait()`, if you `wait()` inside, then it is no longer async, but a synchronous job, that's the sync example. `await` inside the `Parallel.for()` simply mean `come back here when finished`, but it is meaningless, as the `Parallel.for` ended after kicking start all tasks. If you want to use `async-await`, simply use `for-loop` with `Task.WaitAll/WhenAll`.

Comment: @MatrixTai `Parallel.For` with async lambda is finished, but the tasks, which was started with `Parallel.For` are still running and will print "ended", if you wait __outside__ of `Parallel.For`, e.g.with `Task.Delay(2000).Wait();` So the statement "ended" will never be reached __in your code__ is wrong.

Comment: @Rekshino, okay, I understand your concern, I clarify it a bit more.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe the problem clearly. The above is the pseudo code I wrote. I just want to restore the concurrent scene. I don't need to wait for the output "ended", call and create the TaskCompletionSource instance through the synchronous method. In the case of concurrency, create the instance more than My CPU core number will be slow, I have tried setting ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100); but this does not solve the problem at all.

Comment: @汪泽林, you may want to use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Parallel_For_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelOptions_System_Action_System_Int32_System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelLoopState__ , with `new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }`