# Unloading NativeAOT compiled dll

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winapi, dll

With .NET 7's NativeAOT compilation. We can now load a C# dll as regular Win32 module.

```
HMODULE module = LoadLibraryW("AOT.dll");
auto hello = GetProcAddress(module, "Hello");
hello();
```

This works fine and prints some stuff in console.

However, when unloading the dll. It simply doesn't work. No matter how many times I call `FreeLibrary("AOT.dll")`, `GetModuleHandle("AOT.dll")` still returns the handle to the module, implying that it did not unload successfully.

My "wild guess" was that the runtime has some background threads still running (GC?), so I enumerated all threads and use [NtQueryInformationThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationthread) to retrive the start address of each thread then call `GetModuleHandleEx` with `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` to get the module where the thread started, the result were as follows.

Before:

```
THREAD ID      = 7052
base priority  = 8
delta priority = 0
Start address: 00007FF69D751613
Module: 00007FF69D740000 => CppRun.exe


THREAD ID      = 3248
base priority  = 8
delta priority = 0
Start address: 00007FFEF1F42B20
Module: 00007FFEF1EF0000 => ntdll.dll


THREAD ID      = 7160
base priority  = 8
delta priority = 0
Start address: 00007FFEF1F42B20
Module: 00007FFEF1EF0000 => ntdll.dll
```

After:

```
THREAD ID      = 7052
base priority  = 8
delta priority = 0
Start address: 00007FF69D751613
Module: 00007FF69D740000 => CppRun.exe


THREAD ID      = 3248
base priority  = 8
delta priority = 0
Start address: 00007FFEF1F42B20
Module: 00007FFEF1EF0000 => ntdll.dll


THREAD ID      = 7160
base priority  = 8
delta priority = 0
Start address: 00007FFEF1F42B20
Module: 00007FFEF1EF0000 => ntdll.dll


THREAD ID      = 5944
base priority  = 8
delta priority = 0
Start address: 00007FFEF1F42B20
Module: 00007FFEF1EF0000 => ntdll.dll


THREAD ID      = 17444
base priority  = 10
delta priority = 0
Start address: 00007FFE206DBEF0
Module: 00007FFE206D0000 => AOT.dll
```

"CppRun.exe" is my testing application.

As you can see, two additional threads were spawned. One from ntdll (5944), and one from my AOT compiled dll (17444).

I don't know what the leftover thread in "AOT.dll" was for (maybe GC?), but I force-terminated it successfully (definitely unhealthy, I know).

However, when I tried to open the thread in ntdll (5944), it throws an exception

> An invalid thread, handle %p, is specified for this operation. Possibly, a threadpool worker thread was specified

Given that, I assume .NET starts a threadpool worker during initilization? How can I stop that pool and unload the dll?

Or, is there a better way for unloading a NativeAOT compiled dll?

Update: I've hooked the `CreateThreadPool` function, but the runtime doesn't call it. Still trying to figure out what spawned that thread.

Comment: The OS does, [starting at Win10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34826385/17034).  That is not your problem, surely AOT ensures that the module cannot be unloaded.  It is a basic security feature.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the advice, that thread was indeed irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

NativeAOT(aka CoreRT) compiled dll was unloadable at first, but Microsoft later blocked the functionality due to memory leak and crash on process exit. See [this PR](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/pull/7011) for more details.
This answer simply restores the functionality using detour hook and does not deal with the memory leak <s>nor the crash</s>. Use it at your own risk.

I was able to prevent the access violation crash by manually freeing the FLS(fiber-local storage) created by .NET. [Here](https://github.com/Sardelka9515/AotTest/blob/master/CppRun/CppRun.cpp) is a simple demo.

Original answer below:

Turns out that thread is used by Windows 10 for parallel library loading(TppWorkerThread) and isn't the problem.

I ended up inspecting the winapi call with [this handy tool](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor), and found that .NET is calling `GetModuleHandleEx` with the `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_PIN` flag, thus preventing the module from unloading.
[image: .NET calling GetModuleHandleEx]

So I hooked `GetModuleHandleEx` to intercept calls and shift out the flag.
Voila! Now I can unload the NativeAOT compiled dll.

I know this approach is quite hacky, but at least it works.
If anyone happen to have a better solution, please let me know.